# F# scan a buffer finding the last part that begins \c\f and not followed by comma

Tags: arrays, csv, f#

Trying to find an elegant F# solution for this.  I'm reading 1000 bytes from a file into a buffer, "buff".  That part is easy.

Now, I want to scan the buffer looking for the last occurrence of a two-character combination:

Either a carriage return ('\r') or a line feed ('\f') that is *not* followed by a comma.

When I've found that, I need to find the next CR or LF (or the end of the buffer) and print the contents in between as a string.

Context: The file is a CSV file and I want the last line that has some non-empty value in the first column.

Comment: Maybe regex is the best tool for this.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you are reading CSV files, then it might be better idea to use [CSV type provider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html). This gives you a nice typed access to CSV files and it has a couple of options that you can use for dealing with messy CSV files (e.g. if you need to skip a few lines). Alternatively, the F# Data library also has [CSV parser](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvFile.html), which lets you read the file using untyped API.

That said, if you really want to implement parsing on your own, then the following example should illustrate the idiomatic approach. I'm not sure I understand your problem exactly, but say we have:

```
let input = "start \r body \r, comma"
let buff = input.ToCharArray()
```

I believe you want to find the region between `\r` and `\r,`. You can do this using a recursive function that remembers the end of the range and the start of the range and decrements the starting range as it iterates over the string. You can use pattern matching to detect the cases that you need:

```
let rec findRange startLoc endLoc = 
  if startLoc < 0 then failwith "reached beginning"
  match buff.[startLoc], buff.[startLoc+1] with
  | ('\r' | '\f'), ',' -> findRange (startLoc - 1) startLoc
  | ('\r' | '\f'), _ -> startLoc, endLoc
  | _, _ -> findRange (startLoc - 1) endLoc
```

Using this, we can now get the range and get the required substring:

```
let s, e = findRange (buff.Length-2) (buff.Length-1)
input.Substring(s + 1, e - s - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Elegant is in the eye of the beholder but one approach is implementing a matcher type. A matcher is function that given an input string and a position either succeeds returning a new matcher state with an updated position or fails.

```
// A matcher state holds a string and the position
[<Struct>]
type MatcherState =
  {
    Input : string
    Pos   : int
  }

  static member New i p : MatcherState = { Input = i       ; Pos = p         }

  member x.Reposition p : MatcherState = { Input = x.Input ; Pos = p         }
  member x.AdvanceBy i  : MatcherState = { Input = x.Input ; Pos = x.Pos + i }

  member x.Current      = x.Input.[x.Pos]
  member x.InRange      = x.Pos >= 0 && x.Pos < x.Input.Length
  member x.Eos          = x.Pos >= x.Input.Length

// A Matcher is a function that given a MatcherState
//  returns Some MatcherState with a new position if successful
//  otherwise returns None
type Matcher  = MatcherState -> MatcherState option
```

By defining a few active patterns we can pattern match for the line start:

```
// Matches a line start
let mlineStart =
  fun ms ->
    match ms with
    // Bad cases, new line followed by WS + Comma
    | Cr (Ln (Ws (Comma _ | Eos _)))
    | Ln (Ws (Comma _ | Eos _))     -> mbad
    // Good cases, new line not followed by WS + Comma
    | Cr (Ln (Ws ms))
    | Ln (Ws ms)                    -> mgood ms
    // All other cases bad
    | _                             -> mbad
```

Note: I handle new line followed by whitespace + comma here.

The line end is matched similar:

```
// Matches a line end
let mlineEnd =
  fun ms ->
    match ms with
    // Good cases, new line or EOS
    | Cr (Ln ms)
    | Ln ms
    | Eos ms      -> mgood ms
    // All other cases bad
    | _           -> mbad
```

Finally we scanBackward looking for the line start and if we find it scanForward from that position until we find the line end.

```
match scanBackward testCase testCase.Length mlineStart with
| None          -> printfn "No matching line start found"
| Some startPos ->
  // Scan forwards from line start until we find a line end
  match scanForward testCase startPos mlineEnd with
  | None        -> printfn "Line start found @%d, but no matching line end found" startPos
  | Some endPos ->
    let line = testCase.Substring (startPos, endPos - startPos)
    printfn "Line found: %s" line
```

Matcher is actually a simplistic parser but that produces no values and that support scanning forward and backwards. The approach I have chosen is not the most efficient. If efficiency is important it can be improved by applying parser combinator techniques used by for example FParsec.

Hope this was interesting. I am sure someone can up with a shorter regex solution but what fun is that?

Full example follows (no quality guarantees given, use it as an inspiration)

```
// A matcher state holds a string and the position
[<Struct>]
type MatcherState =
  {
    Input : string
    Pos   : int
  }

  static member New i p : MatcherState = { Input = i       ; Pos = p         }

  member x.Reposition p : MatcherState = { Input = x.Input ; Pos = p         }
  member x.AdvanceBy i  : MatcherState = { Input = x.Input ; Pos = x.Pos + i }

  member x.Current      = x.Input.[x.Pos]
  member x.InRange      = x.Pos >= 0 && x.Pos < x.Input.Length
  member x.Eos          = x.Pos >= x.Input.Length

// A Matcher is a function that given a MatcherState
//  returns Some MatcherState with a new position if successful
//  otherwise returns None
type Matcher  = MatcherState -> MatcherState option

let mgood ms  = Some ms
let mbad      = None

// Matches EOS
let meos : Matcher =
  fun ms ->
    if ms.Eos then 
      mgood ms
    else 
      mbad

// Matches a specific character
let mch ch : Matcher =
  fun ms ->
    if not ms.InRange then
      mbad
    elif ms.Current = ch then 
      mgood <| ms.AdvanceBy 1 
    else mbad

// Matches zero or more whitespaces
let mws : Matcher =
  fun ms ->
    let rec loop pos =
      if pos < ms.Input.Length then
        let ch = ms.Input.[pos]
        if ch = ' ' then 
          loop (pos + 1) 
        else 
          mgood <| ms.Reposition pos
      else
        mgood <| ms.Reposition pos
    loop (max ms.Pos 0)

// Active patterns
let (|Eos|_|)   = meos
let (|Comma|_|) = mch ','
let (|Cr|_|)    = mch '\r'
let (|Ln|_|)    = mch '\n'
let (|Ws|_|)    = mws

// Matches a line start
let mlineStart =
  fun ms ->
    match ms with
    // Bad cases, new line followed by WS + Comma
    | Cr (Ln (Ws (Comma _ | Eos _)))
    | Ln (Ws (Comma _ | Eos _))     -> mbad
    // Good cases, new line not followed by WS + Comma
    | Cr (Ln (Ws ms))
    | Ln (Ws ms)                    -> mgood ms
    // All other cases bad
    | _                             -> mbad

// Matches a line end
let mlineEnd =
  fun ms ->
    match ms with
    // Good cases, new line or EOS
    | Cr (Ln ms)
    | Ln ms
    | Eos ms      -> mgood ms
    // All other cases bad
    | _           -> mbad

// Scans either backward or forward looking for a match
let scan steps input pos (m : Matcher) =
  let rec loop ms =
    match m ms with
    | Some mms  ->
      if steps < 0 then
        Some mms.Pos
      else
        Some ms.Pos
    | None      ->
      if steps = 0 then 
        None
      elif steps > 0 && ms.Pos >= ms.Input.Length then
        None
      elif steps < 0 && ms.Pos < 0 then
        None
      else
        loop <| ms.AdvanceBy steps
  loop (MatcherState.New input (min input.Length (max 0 pos)))

let scanForward   = scan 1
let scanBackward  = scan -1

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  // Some test cases
  let testCases = 
    [|
    """1,2,3,4
4,5,6,7"""
    """1,2,3,4
4,5,6,7
"""
    """1,2,3,4
4,5,6,7
,2,3,4
"""
    """1,2,3,4
  4,5,6,7
,2,3,4
"""
    |]

  for testCase in testCases do
    // Scan backwards from end until we find a line start
    match scanBackward testCase testCase.Length mlineStart with
    | None          -> printfn "No matching line start found"
    | Some startPos ->
      // Scan forwards from line start until we find a line end
      match scanForward testCase startPos mlineEnd with
      | None        -> printfn "Line start found @%d, but no matching line end found" startPos
      | Some endPos ->
        let line = testCase.Substring (startPos, endPos - startPos)
        printfn "Line found: %s" line

  0
```

Comment: Where do I find FSharp.Data? Nuget tells me: Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'FSharp.Data'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package FSharp.Data
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package],
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage

Comment: Solved that.  Got FSharp.Data.  Want to use the basic parser (since the csv format will be unknown), but I cannot load the whole thing (sometimes many megabytes).  Can I find the number of lines then only ask for the first n and last n lines?